# Modify a property of another component if a property changes value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular project that contains three components - an item, a location, and a parent that uses both of them. They are defined as follows:

**item.ts:**

```
export class Item {
  hours: number;
}
```

**item.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  template: `<div>Hours: {{ model.hours }}</div>`
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @Input('item') model: Item;
}
```

**location.ts:**

```
export class Location {
  local: boolean;
}
```

**location.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from './location';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-location',
  template: `<div><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.local"></div>`
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @Input('location') model: Location;
}
```

**parent.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './item';
import { Location } from './location';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-item [item]="item"></app-item>
    <app-location [location]="location"></app-location>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  item: Item = new Item();
  location: Location = new Location();

  // ???
}
```

The `???` comment is where the problem lies. When the `local` property of the `Location` is set to `true`, I want to explicitly set the `hours` property of the `Item` to 8.

I have looked through the Angular docs and a number of examples but haven't been able to figure out how to change a property in one component when a property in another changes.

What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `ngModelChange` event handler to `location.component.ts` and emit the event to the parent component:

#### location.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-location',
  template: `<div><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.local" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></div>`
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @Input('location') model: Location;
  @Output('change') change;

  onChange() {
    this.change.emit($event);
  }
}
```

#### parent.component.ts:

Parent component should listen for the event and update the `item`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-item [item]="item"></app-item>
    <app-location [location]="location" (change)="updateItem($event)"></app-location>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  item: Item = new Item();
  location: Location = new Location();

  updateItem(value) {
    item.property = 8;
  }

}
```

Another option would to register a service in the `parent.component` providers and inject it into both item and location component. They can communicate through the service.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your question : What are my options?**

There are 2 options for you if you want to communicate with compoenents

1:
Use `@Input` and `@Output`

> @Input : When you want to pass data from parent component to child
>
> @Output : When you want to pass data from child to parent

2:
Use Service:

> Use service at parent level with provider , So other child component
>   can access same service with same state